# String and null pointers in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, tostring

The following code makes me mad:

```
private String blahBlah(){
    return null;
}

@Test
public void myTest(){
    System.out.println(blahBlah()); //Good, output "null"
    Object obj = blahBlah();
    System.out.println(obj.toString()) //Good as above
    //System.out.println(blahBlah().toString()); //Bad, NullPointerException
    //System.out.println(((Object)blahBlah()).toString()); //Bad as above
}
```

Can anyone explain the above behavior?

UPDATE:

The above code is NOT the truth. What I actually experienced is that I received NullPointerException and I track back to the call of toString(), and I tried different workarounds including in-statement casting but it does'nt work. But after I use seperated cast I accidentally removed the `toString()` call so it WORKED.

Comment: Erm... You sure the third line of `myTest` *doesn't* throw an exception?

Comment: Sorry, I have changed from the observed code. I will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy.

You can print a `null`; you just can't de-reference a `null` value.

Comment: This explain is enough for the direct call of `toString()`. However, how would you explain the difference of the in-statement cast and the separated cast?

Comment: @EarthEngine, duffymo is correct.  The simplest explanation to your code example above is that `blahBlah()` is not consistently returning `null` or you are not running the code in that sample.  Have you ruled both of those out in a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are returning a string pointing at null instead of pointing at a string with the value null. Try changing return null to return "".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.valueOf(Object)` to get the `toString` output from an object, or `null` if the value passed in is `null`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)

> ```
> public static String valueOf(Object obj)
> ```
>
> Returns the string representation of the `Object` argument.
>
> **Parameters:**
>   `obj` - an Object.
>
> **Returns:**
>   if the argument is `null`, then a string equal to `"null"`; otherwise, the value of `obj.toString()` is returned.